# i need to pass a variable to my function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm sure this is simple for most of you, but i'm struggling to learn this concept. i just need a little help. i've commented enough to explain what's going on. thanks!

```
//tabNavItem is an anchor link
$(tabNavItem).on("click", function(e){
    var currSlide = $(this).attr("rel");
    console.log(currSlide); // right here the value is equal to the rel of the link i click. this is correct!                   
    slideAnimation(); // i tried slideAnimation.call(currSlide) but got nothing and i tried slideAnimation(currSlide) and got 1 every time
    e.preventDefault();

});

function slideAnimation(){

    allTabs.hide();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + currSlide).show();                          
    $("." + tabNavClass + " a[rel=" + currSlide + "]").addClass('active');          

    console.log(currSlide); //right now this equals 1, the rel of the first item.

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must declare the function as actually accepting a parameter, like so:

```
function slideAnimation(currSlide){
```

You can then pass the parameter when calling it

```
slideAnimation(currSlide);
```

In case you're not aware, note that JavaScript doesn't attempt to ensure the type of the parameter, and it isn't necessary for the parameter to have the same name as the value being passed.

Comment: thanks! i tried each of these at one point, guess i just didn't do them at the same time. thanks for helping me! i'll accept this ASAP!

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add an argument here
function slideAnimation(item){
    allTabs.hide();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $("#" + item).show();                          
    $("." + tabNavClass + " a[rel=" + currSlide + "]").addClass('active');          
};

//then call it like this 
$(tabNavItem).on("click", function(e){
    var currSlide = $(this).attr("rel");
    slideAnimation(currSlide);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: add a parameter to `slideAnimation`:

```
function slideAnimation (currSlide){
    // snip
}
```